# Extending the application core

Tags: linux, autotools, xbmc

I'm working on a new type of navigation window. This new window (which I've called MultiNav) is intended to allow the user navigate through video, music and images in the same window, this window has three controls that allow the user to select to content type he wants to navigate.

Everything compiles, but I'm not able to link.  The reason is the project is not able to find the object code (*.o files) since I've not include my changes into the build process (./configure  make).

I can tell the project is autotools generated, but I can't find any of the files **configure.ac** or **Makefile.am**.

**Questions**:

1 - How can I include my code into Kodi/XBMC code distribution?

2 - Which are the files I've to edit to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to findout how to notify xbmc/kodi project about new windows code.

In the folder `xbmc/windows` there is a file called `Makefile.in` that's the file that has to be edited in order to add your new code (for a window).

When the whole application is compiled, the code in this folder will be compiled into a static library called `windows.a`. Which will be linked to the main application binary.